# CartThrob and CT Admin reporting email address

Tags: add-on, cartthrob, email

I'm using CT Admin with my Cartthrob store.
Currently all my reports with CT Admin use the EE site's webmaster name and email address for the values. I would prefer to keep our agency as the webmaster email and have a setting somewhere (if possible) to use in the invoice/report pages.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean the "reports"? Are you talking about the Print Invoice and/or Packing Slip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest update to CT Admin (1.5.1) has this capability. Just edit in the settings area.

Comment: I'll give you a point for that ;)